# Nifi Content Viewer

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm in the process of upgrading to NiFi 1.2 and have noticed something with the InvokeHTTP on 1.2 where the content view is unable to display the Content of a response.... This same flow is working fine in our 1.1.x cluster.  We're doing a GET that returns a JSON response.  I look at the Flowfile Attributes in the paused queue, and the Content-Type seems to be set correctly to application/json.  I've even tried to send downstream to an UpdateAttribute and change the mime.type to text/plain.

I'm able to download the file and it looks fine...

Is there some setting/configuration in 1.2 that  I need to set to allow the viewer to view the JSON Content?

Below is some screenshots of the viewer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can't reproduce it. tried InvokeHTTP with http://time.jsontest.com/ and response successfully displayed.

could you provide more info : file size, content, stacktrace from log file, ...

Comment: Are you running on a cluster or stand-alone? As Pierre mentioned this is possibly related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3937 . I built 1.3 and deployed to our test cluster and it appear to be fixed.